# how do i find a complete list of available torque pbs queues?

Tags: queue, pbs, torque

Q: How do I find the available PBS queues on the "typical" Torque MPI system?
(asking our admin takes 24+ hours, and the system changes with constant migration)

(for example, "Std8" is one possible queue)

> #PBS -q  Std8

Answer (score 35):

The admin finally got back. To get a list of queues on our hpc system, the command is:

> $ qstat -q

Answer (score 26):

```
qstat -f -Q
```

shows available queues and details about the limits (cputime, walltime, associated nodes etc.)

Answer (score 9):

How about simply "pbsnodes" - that should probably tell you more than you care to know.  Or I suppose "qstat -Q".

Comment: The confusing thing is that the queue name is "default", so I didn't see it when I ran your "qstat -Q".

Answer (score 2):

Run

```
qhost -q
```

to see the `node-queue` mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
qmgr -c 'p q'
```

The p and q are for print queues.

Comment: In most cases this would print `No Active Queues, nothing done`. On the other hand the `p s` command would print all queues associated with all servers since no active server is set. Yet it would print a lot of extra info that may or may not be useful.